# Cannot go to MainActivity when using LiveData

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, splash-screen, android-livedata

I have splash screen without a layout file. This is what I have tried:

```
 public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!isNotAuthenticated()) {
            openLoginInActivity();
        } else {
            openMainActivity();
        }

        finish();
    }

    private void openMainActivity() {
        viewModel.idLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent); //Go to MainActivity
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using this code, I get this error:

```
2019-09-03 12:03:06.615 1871-1934/? E/ViewRootImpl[myapp]: Could not unlock surface
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at android.view.Surface.nativeUnlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
    at android.view.Surface.unlockSwCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:382)
    at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:363)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3339)
```

If i get the creation if the intent outside `onChanged()`, everything works fine. I have added a log statement and `onChanged` is not even triggered. So how can I move to the next activity without that error?

**Edit:**

```
public class SplashViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private SplashRepository splashRepository;
    MutableLiveData<String> idLiveData;

    @Inject
    SplashViewModel(SplashRepository splashRepository) {
        this.splashRepository = splashRepository;
        idLiveData = splashRepository.addIdToLiveData();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your viewmodel logic as well?

Comment: @AkshayRaiyani Just added. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I used live data in Splash Activity

```
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity<ActivitySplashBinding, SplashViewModel>() {
override val mViewModel: SplashViewModel by currentScope.inject()

override fun getLayoutResId(): Int {
    return R.layout.activity_splash
}

override fun initialization() {

}

override fun initializeObserver() {
    mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it) {
            launchActivityWithFinish<LoginActivity>()
        }
    })
}}
```

Here is My SplashViewModel

```
class SplashViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(SPLASH_TIME_OUT)
        liveData.postValue(true)
    }
}}
```

My SplashActivity In java

```
public class SplashActivity1 extends BaseActivity<ActivitySplashBinding, SplashViewModel> {
@NotNull
@Override
protected SplashViewModel getMViewModel() {
    return new SplashViewModel();
}

@Override
public int getLayoutResId() {
    return R.layout.activity_splash;
}

@Override
public void initialization() {

}

@Override
public void initializeObserver() {
    getMViewModel().getLiveData().observe(this, aBoolean -> {
        if (aBoolean) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", "id");
            startActivity(intent); //Go to MainActivity
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

My SplashViewModel In Java

```
public class SplashViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>(false);

public SplashViewModel(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> liveData.postValue(true),SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}}
```

It perfectly works for me in Kotlin & Java both

Comment: Please help me with that in Java, I don't know Kotlin. Thanks.

Comment: But note that the problem is that onChanged is not even called.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I try it from my side and it's given me a perfect result.

Comment: I don't understand one thing, since it's a simple splash page, why to create a layout? Beside that, why to use a postDetayed?

Comment: When you have to some animation on Splash then we need to create a layout for that. :)

Comment: I don't need any animation, I'm adding a simple background directly in the xml file using styles. Is it mandatory to have a layout?

Comment: Even if I add a layout file, doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with navigation in the past. I usually fixed them by verifying in `onChanged` that the parameter (in your case the String id) is not null and inside call a view model method that changes the id to null.

```
viewModel.idLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String id) {
                if(id != null) {
                  viewModel.navigationDone();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("id", id);
                  startActivity(intent); //Go to MainActivity
                }
            }
        });
```

where navigationDone is a view model method like:

```
void onNavigationDone() {
    idLiveData.setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks but the problem is that `onChanged` is not even called. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the value of idLiveData instead of assigning a new LiveData to it. I think that might be the reason for onChanged not being called.

Comment: And how should I do that?

Comment: A simple way to test it would be to replace the line `idLiveData = splashRepository.addIdToLiveData();` with `idLiveData.setValue('someId')`. Just to see if onChanged gets called.

Comment: Let me check this.

Comment: I've hard coded an id and I have the same problem :(

Comment: I see that your Observer is of type _User_ `Observer<User>` but the observed value **id** is of type String. I think that your Observer should be `Observer<String>`. If this is not it, I don't know what else it could be from the information provided. (when testing this also keep the hard coded id thing that I suggested above)

Comment: My mistake, should be `new Observer<String>()`. Just edited my question. Thanks anyway.